# Using BeautifulSoup to pull multiple posts from a single blog archive page, without scripts

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the authors, title, date, and post content out of a series of WordPress and Blogger blog archive pages. I've saved the pages down so I'm not pinging the server repeatedly. I've got the other parts working, but I can't seem to both get *all* the posts from each file *and* also not get the "add-to-any" or "sociable" or other messy script from the bottom. Here's where I am.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

file_list = open ("hafiles.txt", "r")
posts_file = open ("haposts.txt","w")


for indurl in file_list:
    indurl = indurl.rstrip("\n")
    with open(indurl,"r") as ha_file:
     soup_ha = BeautifulSoup(ha_file)

    #works the second find gets rid of the sociable crap
    # this is the way it looks on the page <div class='post-body'>

    posts = soup_ha.find("div", class_="post-body").find_all("p")


    #tried a trick i saw on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458353/cleaning-text-string-after-getting-body-text-using-beautifulsoup
    #no joy
    #posts = soup_ha.find("div", class_="post-body")
    #text = [''.join(s.findAll(text=True))for s in posts.findAll('p')] 
    text = str(posts) + "\n" + "\n"
    posts_file.write (text)

print ("All done!")



file_list.close()
posts_file.close()
```

So if I do a find_all and get all the posts (not even sure I am actually getting them all), then I get the script. I can get pretty posts with no script at least two ways if I just use find.  I have a list of files, each file has several posts to extract.
I've searched here at stackoverflow and on the web.

eta:the input is a really messy webpage with a ton of scripts at the top, all the css definitions on the page, then

```
<div id='main-wrapper'>
<div class='main section' id='main'><div class='widget Blog' id='Blog1'>
<div class='blog-posts'>
<h2 class='date-header'>27 February, 2007</h2>
<div class='post uncustomized-post-template'>
<a name='edit'></a>
<h3 class='post-title'>
<a href='http:// edited for anon.html'>edit</a>
</h3>
<div class='post-header-line-1'></div>
<div class='post-body'>
<style>span.fullpost{display:none;}</style>
<p>edit this is post text - what i want</p>
<script type='text/javascript'>
          var permlink='edit';
          var title='edit';

          var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
          var number = 0;
          for(i=0; i <spans.length; i++){
                var c = " " + spans[i].className + " ";
                if (c.indexOf("fullpost") != -1) {
                number++;
                }
                }

                if(number != memory){document.write('<p></p><a href=' + permlink + '>"'+ title + '" continues...</a>') }
           memory = number;
           </script>
<div style='clear: both;'></div>
</div>
<div class='post-footer'>
<p class='post-footer-line post-footer-line-1'>
<span class='post-author'>
Posted by
this is the author name, also want, have way to get
</span>
<span class='post-timestamp'>
at
<a class='timestamp-link' href='http://edit' title='permanent link'>2:53 pm</a>
</span>
<span class='post-comment-link'>
<a class='comment-link' href='edit' onclick=''>1 comments</a>
</span>
<span class='post-backlinks post-comment-link'>
<a class='comment-link' href='edit'>Links to this post</a>
</span>
<span class='post-icons'>
<span class='item-control blog-admin pid-edit'>
<a href='edit' title='Edit Post'>
<img alt='' class='icon-action' height='18' src='http://img2.blogblog.com/img/icon18_edit_allbkg.gif' width='18'/>
</a>
</span>
</span>
</p>
<p class='post-footer-line post-footer-line-2'>
<span class='post-labels'>
Labels:
<a href='edit' rel='tag'>edi</a>
</span>
</p>
<p class='post-footer-line post-footer-line-3'></p>
</div>
</div>
<h2 class='date-header'>26 February, 2007</h2>
<div class='post uncustomized-post-template'>
<a name='5518681505930320089'></a>
<h3 class='post-title'>
<a href='edit'>edit</a>
</h3>
<div class='post-header-line-1'></div>
<div class='post-body'>
<style>span.fullpost{display:none;}</style>
<p>edit post text, what I want.</p>
<script type='text/javascript'>
          var permlink='http://edit';
          var title='edit';

          var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
          var number = 0;
          for(i=0; i <spans.length; i++){
                var c = " " + spans[i].className + " ";
                if (c.indexOf("fullpost") != -1) {
                number++;
                }
                }

                if(number != memory){document.write('<p></p><a href=' + permlink + '>"'+ title + '" continues...</a>') }
           memory = number;
           </script>
<div style='clear: both;'></div>
</div>
<div class='post-footer'>
<p class='post-footer-line post-footer-line-1'>
<span class='post-author'>
Posted by
edit author name
</span>
<span class='post-timestamp'>
at
<a class='timestamp-link' href='edit' title='permanent link'>9:00 am</a>
</span>
<span class='post-comment-link'>
<a class='comment-link' href='edit' onclick=''>5
comments</a>
</span>
<span class='post-backlinks post-comment-link'>
<a class='comment-link' href='edit'>Links to this post</a>
</span>
<span class='post-icons'>
<span class='item-control blog-admin pid-edit'>
<a href='edit' title='Edit Post'>
<img alt='' class='icon-action' height='18' src='http://img2.blogblog.com/img/icon18_edit_allbkg.gif' width='18'/>
</a>
</span>
</span>
</p>
<p class='post-footer-line post-footer-line-2'>
<span class='post-labels'>
Labels:
<a href='edit' rel='tag'>edit</a>,
<a href='edit' rel='tag'>edit</a>
</span>
</p>
<p class='post-footer-line post-footer-line-3'></p>
</div>
</div>
<h2 class='date-header'>22 February, 2007</h2>
<div class='post uncustomized-post-template'>
<a name='edit'></a>
```

Yuck! so i have maybe 20 or so files each with 1 to maybe 10 posts in them (this has 2)... what would be lovely is a csv or excel file that was like
date author title postcontent

in columns, one row per.
i'll take a file with just post content with some space between each post. I am fine with some links in the text and some bolds and lists and whatnot, but I don't want all the messy scripts.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example for one single page with multiple posts:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(open('test.html'))
posts = []
for post in soup.find_all('div', class_='post'):
    title = post.find('h3', class_='post-title').text.strip()
    author = post.find('span', class_='post-author').text.replace('Posted by', '').strip()
    content = post.find('div', class_='post-body').p.text.strip()
    date = post.find_previous_sibling('h2', class_='date-header').text.strip()

    posts.append({'title': title,
                  'author': author,
                  'content': content,
                  'date': date})
print posts
```

For the html you've posted, it prints:

```
[{'content': u'edit this is post text - what i want', 
  'date': u'27 February, 2007', 
  'author': u'this is the author name, also want, have way to get', 
  'title': u'edit'}, 
 {'content': u'edit post text, what I want.', 
  'date': u'26 February, 2007', 
  'author': u'edit author name', 
  'title': u'edit'}]
```

Comment: awesome! you make it look so simple! glad I asked :)

Comment: @ChristinaP hope you wouldn't say "Yuck" looking at the HTML next time :) (ok, it can be messy)